# How to write query for the below scenario in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Tables:

**Users**

```
userid       username     imageurl
1            venkat       http://test.jpg
2            raghu        http://test1.jpg
3            ravi         http://test2.jpg
```

**Friends**

```
id    userid    frienduserid     status
1     1           2              true
2     2           1              false
```

**LogStatus**

```
id   userid   sessionid
1     1       7482748
2     1       8274282
3     2       3123123
```

If I pass `userid=1` then need to pull his friends `username,imageurl,status` and any of his friends having at least one `sessionid` then give status as "true".

As of I am able to join users, friends table giving his friends `username,imageurl` and `status`. But how to check any one of his having at least one `sessionid`?

My query:

```
var result = from pa in cxt.Users
             join us in cxt.Friends on pa.User_Id equals us.Friend_UserId
             where us.User_Id == incID 
             select new
                    {
                       us.frienduserid,
                       pa.User_Name,
                       pa.ImageURL,
                       us.status
                    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var result = 
from user in cxt.Users
join friend in cxt.Friends on user.UserId equals friend.FriendUserId
where user.UserId == incId
select new
{
    FriendUserId = friend.FriendUserId,
    UserName = user.UserName,
    ImageUrl = user.ImageUrl,
    Status = cxt.LogStatus.Any(s=>s.UserId == user.UserId)
};
```